# Could match expect type when applying functions to a tree structure

Tags: haskell

[image]

```
data Forky a = Tip a | Branch (Forky a) (Forky a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Forky where
    -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Forky a -> Forky b
    fmap f (Tip a) = Tip (f a)
    fmap f (Branch left right) = Branch (fmap f left) (fmap f right)

instance Applicative Forky where
    -- pure :: a -> Forky a
    pure a = Tip a

    -- (<*>) :: Forky (a -> b) -> Forky a -> Forky b
    (<*>) (Branch f g) (Branch left right) = 
        Branch ((fmap f (Branch left right)) (fmap g (Branch left right)))
```

Everything looks good until the last function `(<*>)`

The error tells

```
 ? Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> b0’
                  with actual type ‘Forky (a -> b)’
```

How can I fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Branch f g`, `f` and `g` are not functions of type `a -> b`; they are subtrees of type `Forky (a -> b)`. As such, you need to use `<*>`, not `fmap`, to apply them.

```
(Branch fs gs) <*> (Branch left right) = Branch (fs <*> left) (gs <*> right)
```

Further, you need to consider the case where you have a function in a tip:

```
(Tip f) <*> (Tip a) = ?
```

You should also consider what you will do if the two arguments don't have the same shape:

```
(Tip f) <*> (Branch left right) = ?
(Branch fs gs) <*> (Tip a) = ?
```

Comment: According to the requirement, "tf h<*> t begins with the tree shape of tf , but then each of its Tip f is replaced by the result of fmap f t."  If we use `<*>`, then how can we replace the Tips with fmap f t?

Comment: Which of the three cases I left undefined do you think applies to that case?

Comment: Right; in the case of two `Tip`s, you just want to apply the function and put the result in a new `Tip`. For a `Tip` and a `Branch`, you can use `fmap` to apply the single function to the entire tree. For a `Branch` and a `Tip`, I guess you create a new `Branch` with every function applied to the same single value? That might be a little tricky to work out, but as a hint, you might want to use `($)` in some way.

Answer (score 0):

```
data Forky a = Tip a | Branch (Forky a) (Forky a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
--...
instance Applicative Forky where
    --...
    -- (<*>) :: Forky (a -> b) -> Forky a -> Forky b
    (<*>) (Branch f g) (Branch left right) = 
        Branch ((fmap f (Branch left right)) (fmap g (Branch left right)))
```

Here, during the pattern matching, `Branch` has of `Forky (a -> b) -> Forky (a -> b) -> Forky (a -> b)`, so `f` and `g` must have type of `Forky (a -> b)`. So they cannot be applied to `fmap`.

The correct definition of `<*>` can be:

```
Tip f        <*> x = fmap f x
Branch fs gs <*> x = Branch (fs <*> x) (gs <*> x)
```